# How to invoke a function that accepts Request Object from another function?

Tags: php, function, object

In a PHP OAuth Implementation, there is a function as below:

```
  /**
   * Processes POST requests to /oauth/token.
   */
  public function token(ServerRequestInterface $request) {
    // Extract the grant type from the request body.
    $body = $request->getParsedBody();
    $grant_type_id = !empty($body['grant_type']) ? $body['grant_type'] : 'implicit';

    /*.. CODE TRIMMED ..*/   

    catch (OAuthServerException $exception) {
      watchdog_exception('simple_oauth', $exception);
      $response = $exception->generateHttpResponse(new Response());
    }
    return $response;
  }
```

I think its an instance of:

```
Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;
```

I want to call this function, and pass the body params to this function from another function. Something as below:

```
public function call_token(){

    //Something like this??  
    $request = new ServerRequestInterface();
    $request->setUrl('https://some.url/oauth/token');
    $request->setMethod("POST");

    $request->setHeader(array(
      'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',      
    ));

    $request->addPostParameter(array(
      'grant_type' => 'password',
      'client_id' => '828472a8-f2c5-4e79-a158-ab041d3b313a',
      'client_secret' => 'secret',
      'username' => 'admin',
      'password' => '123'
    ));
    
    $response = $token($request);
}
```

I am not able to figure out how we can call this function.

[This is the full source code](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/simple_oauth/-/blob/8.x-4.x/src/Controller/Oauth2Token.php) where the token code is implemented. I am trying to call this function from another class.

Below is a working CURL request of how requests are made to this endpoint. I however want to emulate the request from within the application.

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://some.url/oauth/token',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => 'grant_type=password&client_id=828472a8-f2c5-4e79-a158-ab041d3b313a&client_secret=secret&username=admin&password=123',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',        
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

Comment: `$token` should be `$this->token`

Comment: Assuming `call_token` and `token` are methods of the same class.

Comment: @Barmar My problem is that I am unable to create a request object. How can I emulate something that comes in a request from within code?

Comment: Why not create the instance of ServerRequestInterface inside the token function? And simply accept parameters?

Comment: @Albab I am not understanding how. How can I do that?

Comment: Your problem is here `$request = new ServerRequestInterface();`. You are trying to instantiate an interface which is not possible. What you want to do is create a `ServerRequest` class that implements `ServerRequestInterface` and pass that class object to the `token` method.